# I have an infinite while loop but i don't see why

Tags: python, while-loop, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to learn how to code really simple neural networks from scratch. However I can't seen to get the training right. Whenever I run my while loop it gets stuck in an infinite loop.
Here is my code:

```
#inputs and targets
x1=[1,0,1]
x2=[0,1,0]
x3=[0,0,1]
inputs=[x1,x2,x3]
targets=[1,0,0,1]

#parameters
np.random.seed(1)
w1 = np.random.random_sample(size = 3)
w1=w1.tolist()
alpha=0.1
itera=0

#activation function
def purelin(z):
    return z

#network
def red(i,w1):
    n=[]
    for inp in i:
        a=inp*w1[inputs.index(i)]
        n.append(a)
    n=sum(n) #sumar inputs*weights (caso sin bias)
    a=purelin(n)
    return a

#forward propagation
def forw(inputs):
    outputs=[]
    for i in inputs:
        x=red(i,w1)
        outputs.append(x)
    return outputs

#error
def error(targets, outputs):
    e=[]
    zip_object = zip(targets, outputs)
    for i, j in zip_object:
        e.append(i-j)
    return e 


#backpropagation 
def back(e):
    w1_=[]
    zip_object2 = zip(w1, e)
    for i, j in zip_object2:
        w1_.append(i-alpha*j)
    return w1_

#training
while itera<1000:
    outputs=forw(inputs)
    e=error(targets,outputs)
    w1=back(e)
    itera=+1
```

I know I still have a lot of work to do but I want to solve this problem so I can tune my code and get results. Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you think that it is an infinite loop? It should stop after 1000 iterations.

Comment: You should add some debugging output.

Comment: It's a typo. `=+` should be `+=`. **</question>**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a minor typing error. At the end of the loop, you aren't incrementing `itera` by one, but are setting it to `+1` .
Just change the last line to `itera += 1`and it should work fine.

Note: Sometimes it may be helpful to print out variables, even if I would always recommend you to debug your code properly.